# How to define custom check according to my rules and how to implement Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I using Python 3.10, Django 4.1.2, djangorestframework==3.14.0 (front separately)

In an order, the products received field is empty by default. As we receive the order, we must remove these elements from the ordered field and transfer them to the received ones.

1. Received products must contain only products from requested products
2. After submitting request with amount of received products, this particular products should be removed from requested Products and adding to `received_products`

I have two ideas for a theoretical implementation.

1. Using the patch, the received_product and the elements in it
2. Separate methods

I have this code:

```
class Orders(models.Model):
    delivery_model_choices = (("Pickup", "Pickup"),
                              ("Delivery", "Delivery"))
    order_status_choices = (("Draft", "Draft"),
                            ("Open", "Open"),
                            ("Partially Received", "Partially Received"),
                            ("Received", "Received"),
                            ("Cancelled", "Cancelled"))
    customer = models.ManyToManyField(Customers)
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Products)
    received_products = ???
    date_create = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    delivery = models.CharField(max_length=40, choices=delivery_model_choices)
    delivery_date = models.DateField()
    order_status = models.CharField(max_length=40, choices=order_status_choices)
    total_price = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

Please, I ask you for a correct example on this implementation. I'm still new to development

Answer (score 1):

I will not write the complete code, but you can try this logic -

Define a Create method for the viewset or views (whatever you use)

```
def create(self, request, format=None):
    request.data is the data that you receive
    all_product_recieved = all products that you have received
    recived_products = all_product_recieved - ordered product
    custom_data = create a new dictionary with valid data
    then ...
    serializer = self.get_serializer(data=custom_data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response()
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Hope this helps.